# how to make tree nodes stick to each other (or minimal fixed gap) without overlapping in d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a binary tree with at least 12 levels. In case of 12th level I have to adjust 2^12 nodes, that's pretty much high and I added a horizontal scroll bar. So, I want all the nodes at last level to stick to each other to save space and horizontal scrolling, as shown in this image:

[image]

I don't want to adjust width of svg every time to squeeze them to fit. I want some proper way to reduce separation between nodes at last level and keep the nodes separation same even if width of svg or container increases. 
Till now I have not found any solution online.

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the depth attribute of the nodes, i.e:

```
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
```

for each level of the tree you can update the gap between them.

In order to give you an idea, take a look at this example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bDBe0xGX1mCLzqYGOqOS?p=preview

Comment: As you can see in image attached (http://i.stack.imgur.com/ApsNP.jpg), my tree chart is starting from top to bottom instead of left to right. I've already used your suggestion to adjust vertical scrolling and it's working fine. Problem is with horizontal scrolling. Please see the image and suggest something :)

Comment: I've updated the plunk and see your point. I'm leaving the plunk in case anyone wants to take it further away.http://plnkr.co/edit/1HGUXyl7o2kc3FuTWit7?p=preview

Comment: Nodes are overlapping while trying to open child nodes. Trying expanding all the nodes and see they are overlapping :(

Comment: Yes you are right. That's why i left the plunk, maybe it will help someone instead of starting from scratch.